# How do you reject a JSON key in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby, json, coffeescript

I have this JSON payload and I'd like to use it in several places and was wondering how to reject two keys from this.

```
@metaTagsAdvanced = {
  App: { comparison: ['was', 'was not'], value: ['Opened in the last two days', 'Opened   in the last two weeks', 'Opened in the last month'], enabled: true },
  AppVersion: { comparison: ['equals', 'not equal', 'greater than', 'less than', 'greater than or equal', 'less than or equal'], value: 'string', enabled: true },
  ControlGroup: { comparison: ['less than', 'less than or equal', 'greater than', 'greater than or equal', 'equals'], value: 'number', numberOptions: {min: 1, max: 10}, enabled: true },
  Country: { comparison: ['is', 'is not'], value: 'country', enabled: true },
  Deliverable: { comparison: ['is', 'is not'], value: ['Push Notification','Local Push Notification', 'App Originated Push', 'In-App Alert', 'In-App Content', 'SMS', 'MMS', 'Email', 'Rich Message'], enabled: true },
  Event: {comparison: {eventNumber: ['did occur N days ago', 'did occur greater than N days ago','did occur greater than or equal to N days ago','did occur less than N days ago','did occur less than or equal to N days ago', 'did not occur N days ago','did not occur greater than N days ago','did not occur greater than or equal to N days ago','did not occur less than N days ago','did not occur less than or equal to N days ago'], standards: ['did occur', 'did not occur']}, value: 'events', enabled: true},
  InstallDate: { comparison: ['before', 'was', 'after', 'within', 'days ago', 'greater than N days ago', 'greater than or equal to N days ago','less than N days ago', 'less than or equal to N days ago'], value: 'date', enabled: true },
  Language: { comparison: ['is', 'is not'], value: 'language', enabled: true },
  LastOpenDate: { comparison: ['before', 'was', 'after', 'within', 'N days ago', 'greater than N days ago', 'greater than or equal to N days ago', 'less than N days ago', 'less than or equal to N days ago'], value: 'date', enabled: true },
  OS: { comparison: ['is', 'is not'], value: ['android', 'ios'], enabled: true },
  PushOpenRate: { comparison: ['greater than or equal', 'less than or equal'], value: ['0', '0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', '0.5', '0.6', '0.7', '0.8', '0.9', '1'], enabled: true },
  Segment: {comparison: ['is in'], value: 'segments', enabled: true},
  Sessions: { comparison: ['less than', 'greater than'], value: 'number', numberOptions: {min: 1}, enabled: true },
  Tag: {comparison: {string: ['is', 'is not', 'contains'], double: ['equals', 'not equal to', 'less than', 'greater than', 'less than or equal', 'greater than or equal'], timestamp: ['before', 'after', 'was', 'within', 'N days ago', 'greater than N days ago', 'greater than or equal to N days ago','less than N days ago','less than or equal to N days ago'], segment: ['is in', 'is not in'], standard: ['exists', 'does not exist']}, value: 'tags', enabled: true},
  Timezone: {comparison: ['is', 'is not'], value: 'timezone', enabled: true}
}
```

So I'm wanting to insert the instance as you can see below. However, how could I change this code to reject/exclude the 'Segment' and 'Timezone' key from above?

```
filters = $.extend({}, @metaTagsAdvanced)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as it would allow me to significantly refactor some of my code! (I'm using coffeescript, hence why it's formatted the way it is!)

Cheers

Comment: Why not a simple for and delete the unwanted keys? O_O

Comment: What is the filename of the file that contains the line `filters = $.extend({}, @metaTagsAdvanced)`?

Comment: It's all in the same file, the `filters = $.extend({}, @metaTagsAdvanced)` is just further down in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a utility library like lodash or underscore that would be more robust than this solution, but you could do something like this if you didn't want to rely on native prototype methods on the Array. Intermittent log statements to show how it gets built up.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TRqG8/

## jQuery only

```
someTags = 
  Foo: {foo: 'bar'}
  Bar: {foo: 'bar'}
  Baz: {foo: 'bar'}

_keys = (obj)-> $.map(obj, (value, key)-> key) # seems odd that key is last but that appears to be the way jQuery 2.1.0 works.

console.log _keys(someTags) # => ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"] 

_in = (arr, key)-> arr.indexOf(key) != -1

console.log _in(_keys(someTags), 'Foo') #=> true 

# there is a native filter function for Array.prototype
_filter = (obj, keys...)->
  objKeys = _keys(obj)
  # a poor man's reduce
  ob = {}
  for k in objKeys
    ob[k] = obj[k] unless _in(keys, k)
  ob

console.log _filter(someTags, 'Bar') #=> Object {Foo: Object, Baz: Object}

console.log $.extend({}, _filter(someTags, 'Bar', 'Baz')) #=> Object {Foo: Object}
```

## Underscore

in contrast, using underscore you could do something like this:

```
someTags = 
  Foo: {foo: 'bar'}
  Bar: {foo: 'bar'}
  Baz: {foo: 'bar'}

console.log _.extend({}, _.omit(someTags, 'Bar'))
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nUSM8/1/

Comment: I've shown using `extend` assuming you are planning on using `extend` expected. If you you just want to filter, you can ignore the calls to extend.

Comment: Jed, this is exactly what I was looking for and I am already using Underscore in my project, so this is super helpful!

Comment: it was quite fun to work through! Food for thought: use capitalized words for constructor functions (the ones you'd use 'new' to create, like `new Object()`). Even though you can use them as keys, you'll save yourself some headache down the road by avoiding that syntax trap.

Comment: How would I extend existing object using Underscore to add someTags? `_.extend({}, _.something(Blah, someTags)`

Comment: `_.extend({Blah: {}}, _.omit(someTags, 'Bar'))` I think is what you want.

Comment: underscore has an amazing annotated source: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-84 and documentation http://underscorejs.org/#extend